# Make Pipenv create the virtualenv in the same folder

Tags: python, pipenv

I want Pipenv to make virtual environment in the same folder with my project (Django).

I searched and found the `PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT` option but I don't know where and how to use this.

Comment: What did you hope that `PIPENV_DOTENV_LOCATION` would do? It does *not* have anything to do with the location of the virtualenv that Pipenv creates.

Comment: @MartijnPieters sorry i edit it i mean `PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT`

Answer (score 111, accepted):

`PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT` is an environment variable, just set it (the value doesn't matter, but must not be empty). Make sure to export it so child processes of the shell can see it:

```
export PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1
```

This causes the virtualenv to be created in the `.venv` directory next to the `Pipfile` file. Use `unset PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT` to remove the option again.

You may want to see if the [`direnv` project](https://direnv.net/) can be useful here. It'll set environment variables for you, automatically, when you enter your project directory, provided you created a `.envrc` file in the project directory and enabled the directory with `direnv allow`. You then can add any such `export` commands to that file.

Comment: thanks for your replay , how can i set this environment variable ? i'm using ubuntu 18.04 server running on vps hosting ? sorry i'm a very newbie with ubuntu stuff

Comment: @DAMAR225: I gave you the syntax for a bash shell environment, just use that when you have a terminal open where you are executing the Pipenv commands.

Comment: So what command should I run if I am using windows powershell? Thank you

Comment: @Serdia: no idea, sorry, not a Windows user.

Comment: Note, that if you install from a requirements.txt with `-r` you should first create the empty Pipfile, so that pipenv knows, next to where it should put .venv

Comment: @Eike: then why use pipenv at all? Just use `virtualenv .venv` to create the virtual env yourself.

Answer (score 95):

This maybe helps someone else. I found another easy way to solve this!

Just make an empty folder inside your project and name it `.venv` and pipenv will use this folder.

Comment: I felt this is simplest answer and its working like charm!!!

Comment: this is the very simple solution as of my opinion.

Comment: I prefer this solution as it: (a) doesn't involve messing with environment variables; (b) applies only to the project I am currently working on.

Answer (score 6):

Try

```sh
PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1 pipenv sync -d
```

Comment: PIPENV_VERBOSITY=-1 PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1 pipenv install --python 3.8.7 would give you a specific python version as well. Sync did not work for me.

Answer (score 6):

**In Three simple steps:**

1. export the variable as

   `export PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1`
2. Create a empty folder and file Pipfile

   `mkdir .venv`

   `touch Pipfile`
3. Then execute

   `pipenv shell`

Comment: i skipped right to step 2 and that worked for me

Answer (score 3):

For the fish shell, use:

```
set -Ux PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT 1
```

Answer (score 3):

For posterity's sake, if you find pipenv is not creating a virtual environment in the proper location, you may have an erroneous Pipfile somewhere, confusing the `pipenv shell` call - in which case I would delete it form path locations that are not explicitly linked to a repository.

Answer (score 3):

This trick worked for me:

- create an empty folder named .venv
- create an empty file named Pipfile
- Run pipenv shell there.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. 
to add, made sure to run >exit
to exit the wrong virtual environment
and then made sure to delete the wrong .venv 
Followed your first 2 steps

Ran this instead:
PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=true pipenv install --dev pipenv shell

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a file named `.env` in your project root folder and include this line:

```
PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1
```

Pipenv will recognize this file and automatically load all key-value pairs defined in it as environment variables before proceeding, as documented [here](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/shell.html#automatic-loading-of-env). This has the same effect as manually defining an environment variable beforehand, except you have to do it only once and it works on any platform.

Defining environment variables in such a "dotenv" file is a fairly widely recognized convention and supported by many tools. See [this article](https://medium.com/@sujathamudadla1213/what-is-the-use-of-env-8d6b3eb94843) for further explanation.